# Assigning coordinates to the dialog in c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a dialog of dimensions 500 and 800 as width and height. By default (0,0) is set to the top-left corner but i need my dialog to map with in given co ordinates. That is I want my dialog to take (-125,-64) as (left,top) and (221,160) as right (bottom). But dialog size have to remain the same.

Comment: Simple scaling. Scale an x in the range [-125,221] to a coordinate in a new range [0,500] and scale a y in the range [-64,160] to a coordinate in a new range [0,800]. Use the resultant x,y.

Comment: It's not clear, what exactly you need. If you need a logical coordinate system, that doesn't coincide with the device coordinate system for GDI rendering, use the [CDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxhhde73.aspx) members `SetViewportExt`/`SetViewportOrg` to set up coordinate mapping.

Answer (score -1):

You can use it simply like
 x=(W/w)(X+a)
y=(H/h)(Y+b )
Means:

```
Int X,Y;//this is the coordinates of a point in the custom box
int x,y;// the coordinates in the main box
int a=-125,b=-64;//the coordinates of the point of the new axis
int w=800,h=500;// the original width and height of the box
int W=225+125;
int H=160+64;
input X,Y;
x=(w/W)*(X-b);
y=(h/H)*(Y-a);
```

Comment: thanks.But aren't there any in built function for mapping custom box to main box.